# How to remove extra column Datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

i have binded itemsource to Datatable for Datagrid .  it shows extra columns how to remove it

My code :

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid"  IsReadOnly="True"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Cus}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

it show extra columns How to remove it ?

Screen shot : 
[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

Set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and `Width="*"` for all Columns

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderId}" Header="OrderId" Width="*"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductId}" Width="*" Header="ProductId"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UnitPrice}" Width="*" Header="UnitPrice"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Width="*" Header="Quantity"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Discount}" Header="Discount"
                           Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Solution 2 :**
You can set like this to achieve your requirement

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,0,0,0" Width="500"
          Name="dataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Cus}" AutoGeneratingColumn="AutoGeneratingColumn"/>

 void dataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
 }
```

Answer (score 24):

You can set the HorizontalAlignment to Left. As described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f8863a39-13e2-4c82-9c16-f22f20e4b99d/extra-column-at-the-end-of-wpf-datagrid)

For example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Answer (score 22):

One way to avoid is to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` (*XAML only approach*).

Provide your own collection of columns and `set width for last column` to `*`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderId}" Header="OrderId"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductId}" Header="ProductId"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UnitPrice}" Header="UnitPrice"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Header="Quantity"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Discount}" Header="Discount"
                           Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Replace bindings for your columns to corresponding properties in your model class.
Output will be like this:

[image]

However, in case you want to distribute available space equally for all columns. You can `set width to * for all columns`. Output will be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was fighting over this for some times now, the `Width="\*"` solved my problem while datagrid `ColumnWidth="*"` not working in my case.

Comment: `ColumnWidth="*"` worked for me, but I had to force rebuild or the XAML designer didn't update.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to:

1. keep AutoGenerateColumns="True" AND
2. keep the columns Width being automatically adjusted to the data from the DataTable rather then have the same width

you need to set "1*" to the last column only. Please:

1) Add the event handler to .xaml

2) Add the following code to .xaml.cs

```
    private void dataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = ((DataGrid)sender).Columns.Count;
        DataGridColumn column = ((DataGrid)sender).Columns[i - 1];
        column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the attribute ColumnWidth="*" in the DataGrid object.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagridname" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This will just give all columns equal sizes though.

Answer (score 0):

Well since its unused space, another way around will be use a weighted width rather than fixed one :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderId}" Header="OrderId" Width="1*"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductId}" Header="ProductId" Width="1*"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UnitPrice}" Header="UnitPrice" Width="1*"/>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Header="Quantity" Width="1*"/>
```