# How to remove last column datatable c#

Tags: c#, xaml, datatable

**EDIT**

I have tried to set the AutoGeneratColumns property to false as suggested in:
[How to remove extra column Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770701/how-to-remove-extra-column-datagrid).

However, all my columns disappear if I do that.

**QUESTION**

I have a data table with program generated columns and rows. However, I get an extra column to the right of my generated columns. What should I write to make it disappear?

The xaml:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MatrixToDataViewConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="ColumnHeaders" ElementName="Results"/>
                    <Binding Path="RowHeaders" ElementName="Results"/>
                    <Binding Path="Values" ElementName="Results"/>
                </MultiBinding>
        </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
      </DataGrid>
```

the convert method

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var myDataTable = new DataTable();

                string[] columns = values[0] as string[];
                string[] rows = values[1] as string[];
                double[,] matrix = values[2] as double[,];

                myDataTable.Columns.Add("---"); //Upper left corner

                foreach (string value in columns)
                {
                    myDataTable.Columns.Add(value);
                }


                foreach (string value in rows)
                {
                    myDataTable.Rows.Add(value);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    int row = System.Convert.ToInt32(matrix[i, 1]) - 1;
                    int column = System.Convert.ToInt32(matrix[i, 0]);
                    myDataTable.Rows[row][column] += matrix[i, 2].ToString() + " to " + matrix[i, 3].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                }

                return myDataTable.DefaultView;
            }
```

Comment: [How to remove extra column Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770701/how-to-remove-extra-column-datagrid)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extra column Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770701/how-to-remove-extra-column-datagrid)

Comment: I have already tried the solution to the linked question but all my columns disappear if I do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused your additional column, so i give you an answer on the title's question:

```
myDataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(myDataTable.Columns.Count - 1);
```

Comment: @Emelie: why is it now more appropriate? If it's not the last column, how to determine tha extra column you want to remove?

Comment: I changed it back... I have tried your solution but it does not remove the unwanted column, it removes the column on its left side.

Comment: Sorry about the change of title... Or is it something else that is confusing?
 @iamCR.

Comment: Your question says extra column at the right and this answer should remove the right last column. But you are saying it removes the left. Better you can attach the image of `DataTable` instead of Grid

Comment: I know. My theory is that the last "column" isn't really a column. So when I try this code it removes the column with 211 to 287 in the first row, that is the column to the left of the "column" that I want to remove.  I do not understand what image you mean @iamCR.

Comment: Then just make the column `Visible = false`. Will that work? @Emelie

Comment: I have tried to do that as per engrmarvins suggestion but it does not have the property visible. I tried it with myDataGrid.Columns[index].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden but no matter what index I write I get an out of range error. @iamCR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149222/discussion-between-iamcr-and-emelie).

Answer (score 0):

You can either remove :

```
DataTable copyDataTable;
copyDataTable = table.Copy();
copyDataTable.Columns.Remove("ColB");
```

or filter using [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
System.Data.DataView view = new System.Data.DataView(yourOriginalTable);
System.Data.DataTable selected = 
        view.ToTable("Selected", false, "col1", "col2", "col6", "col7", "col3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your input data is not correct.
Debug this part.

```
foreach (string value in columns)
{
    myDataTable.Columns.Add(value);
}
```

If you go through it 4 times sth is wrong.

Comment: I have debugged that part but that is unfortunately not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
    myDataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(myDataTable.Columns.Count - 1);
```

Comment: I do not have a datagridview, only a datagrid. myDataGrid.Columns[i] does not contain a definition for Visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think `object[] values` array has four values on which *foreach* loop adds four columns in your DataTable.

And before loop you added a column in DataTable which is `myDataTable.Columns.Add("---");`.

So, now there are five columns in your DataTable.