# How do I get rid of the empty table in my gridview WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

So I recently created a GridView in WPF for my database application.
It holds the usernames and passwords for my website users and it works perfectly,
The only issue is that it adds the empty columns to the right but I have no diea why.
What did I do wrong and how do properly do it?
I cant click the right columns its like its just null.

XML

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserAddRows="False" BorderBrush="Black" Name="dgAccounts" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,103,405,10">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

C#

```
private void RetrieveUserData()
        {
            string line;
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                string accs = wc.DownloadString(Clipboard.GetText());

                using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(accs))
                {
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        newAccounts.Add(new Accounts { Username = theUsername, Password = thePassword });
                    }
                }
            }
            dgAccounts.ItemsSource = newAccounts;
        }
```

[Here you can see what the problem looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moTkP.png)

Comment: How many data members does your Accounts class have ?

Comment: Only 2 they are Account & Member Get; Set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extra column Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770701/how-to-remove-extra-column-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `DataGrid` is a fixed size, the empty column will be generated as a result of your other columns only using the space they need.

Try setting the Width of each column, I suggest using `Width="*"` to ensure the whole grid is used and each column uses an equal amount of space.